# insert multiple rows into table with column that has default value

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I have a table in PostgreSQL and one of the column has default value.
DDL of the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_table_name
(int_column_1 character varying(6) NOT NULL,
 text_column_1 character varying(20) NOT NULL,
 text_column_2 character varying(15) NOT NULL,
 default_column numeric(10,7) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.1,
 time_stamp_column date NOT NULL);
```

I am trying to insert multiple rows in a single query. And in those I have some rows to which I have value for `default_column` and i have some rows to which i don't have any value for `default_column` and want to Postgres to use default value for these rows.

Here's what i tried:

```
INSERT INTO "my_table_name"(int_column_1, text_column_1, text_column_2, default_column, time_stamp_column) 
VALUES
(91,'text_row_11','text_row_21',8,current_timestamp),
(91,'text_row_12','text_row_22',,current_timestamp),
(91,'text_row_13','text_row_23',19,current_timestamp),
(91,'text_row_14','text_row_24',,current_timestamp),
(91,'text_row_15','text_row_25',27,current_timestamp);
```

this gives me an error. So, when i try to insert:

```
INSERT INTO "my_table_name"(int_column_1, text_column_1, text_column_2, default_column, time_stamp_column) 
    VALUES (91,'text_row_12','text_row_22',,current_timestamp), -- i want null to be appended here, so i left it empty. 
--error from this query is: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
```

and

```
INSERT INTO "my_table_name"(int_column_1, text_column_1, text_column_2, default_column, time_stamp_column) 
    VALUES (91,'text_row_14','text_row_24',NULL,current_timestamp), 
-- error from this query is: ERROR:  new row for relation "glycemicindxdir" violates check constraint "food_item_check"
```

So, how do i fix this; And insert value when i have it or have Postgres insert default when I don't have a value?

Comment: Why is **time_stamp** _column defined as `date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `default` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO my_table_name
  (int_column_1,  text_column_1,  text_column_2,  default_column,  time_stamp_column) 
VALUES
  (91, 'text_row_11', 'text_row_21', 8      , current_timestamp), 
  (91, 'text_row_12', 'text_row_22', default, current_timestamp), 
  (91, 'text_row_13', 'text_row_23', 19     , current_timestamp), 
  (91, 'text_row_14', 'text_row_24', default, current_timestamp), 
  (91, 'text_row_15', 'text_row_25', 27     , current_timestamp);
```